# Google geocode on page load, not via an input

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm following this tuorial -https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

**I've put in the code `<?php echo the_field('post_code'); ?>` but I want to geocode it on load, not via an input and submit. How can I do that?**

This is what I have:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.375599, -3.471680);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = '<?php echo the_field('post_code'); ?>';
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;height:250px; width:625px;margin-top:25px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Rob i didnt get u. U want Geocode without giving input address or by submit button? And `<?php echo the_field('post_code'); ?>` what problem in this?

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar Yes, I want to geocode on load. In the tutorial you have to put an address in and click submit. I'm setting the address via `<?php echo the_field('post_code'); ?>`, so I want it to geocode that straight away and place the marker.

Comment: Call `codeAddress` after geocode and map is initialized.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao Like this: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize, codeAddress);`?

Comment: @Rob I think `Subir Kumar Sao` answered ur question. Its what u want right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.375599, -3.471680);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  codeAddress(); // This should do it. Assuming all the code is working.
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the map doesn't load when trying that. I've kept the code below that as is and just added the line you suggested. This is the page I'm working on - http://www.mediwales.com/pictureofhealth/teamworks-design-and-marketing/

Comment: Got it, stupid mistake on my part, your answer worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call `codeAddress()` in `initialize()` passing address as parameter.

```
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.375599, -3.471680);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  codeAddress(address);
}
```